# Incorporating real data when solving a system of ODE's using scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am trying to construct a simple model of a heating system represented by a system of ODEs and solved using scipy's odeint function.

I would like to incorporate 'real' data in this model, for instance external temperature (simulated as a sinewave below). The code below shows my current solution/hack which uses a function called FindVal to interpolate the real data to the timestamp being evaluated by odeint.

This is very slow so I am looking for suggestions as to how this can be done in a better way.

Here is the code...

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import linspace
from numpy import interp
from numpy import sin
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy import array
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import where

def FindVal(timeseries, t):
    ''' finds the value of a timeseries at the time given by the ode solver
            INPUTS: timeseries - [list of times, list of values]
                    t - timestamp being evaluated
            OUTPUTS: interpolated value at t
        '''

    ts_t = timeseries[0]    
    ts_v = timeseries[1]

    # if t is beyond the end of the time series chose the last value
    if t > ts_t[-1]:
        val = ts_v[-1]

    else:
        val = interp(t, ts_t, ts_v)

    return val

def SpaceHeat(Tin, t):
    ''' calculates the change in internal temperature
        INPUTS: Tin - temperature at t - 1
                t - timestep
        OUTPUTS: dTdt - change in T
    '''

    # unpack params
    ma = params['ma'] # mass of air
    ca = params['ca'] # heat capacity of air
    hlp = params['hlp'] # heat loss parameter
    qp = params['qp'] # heater power

    Touts = params['Tout'] # list of outside temps
    Tout = FindVal(Touts, t) # value of Tout in this timestep
    Qonoffs = params['Qonoff'] # list of heater on/offs
    Qonoff = FindVal(Qonoffs, t) # heater state at this timestep

    qin = qp * Qonoff # heat input

    qmass = 0 # ignore mass effects for now

    # calculate energy lost
    qloss = (Tin - Tout) * hlp # 

    # calculate the change in temperature
    dTdt = (qin - qmass - qloss) / (ma * ca)
    return dTdt

def Solve(timeline, Qonoff):

    # simulate the outside temp as a sinewave
    Tout = [timeline, (sin(0.001 * timeline + 1500) * 10) + 2] # outside temp

    # create a dict of model parameters
    global params
    params = {'ma' : 1000.0 * 250, # air mass, kg
          'ca' : 1.0, # air heat capacity j/kg
          'hlp' : 200.0, # home heat loss parameter wk
          'qp' : 10000.0, # heater output w
          'Qonoff' : Qonoff, # list of on off events
          'Tout' : Tout,
          }

    # set the initial temperature
    Tinit = 10.0
    # solve
    temps = odeint(SpaceHeat, Tinit, timeline)

    return temps

# create a timeline for the simulation
timeline = linspace(0, 6000, 96)

# calculate the optimum control
Qonoff = zeros(len(timeline))

temps = Solve(timeline, qonoff)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a while ago and my knowledge has moved on significantly....

The answer to this is that you have to solve an ODE at each step of the external data you want to use, using the results from the previous integration at the start of this new state.

Answer (score 0):

One line is missing, qonoff was not defined.

```
Qonoff = zeros(len(timeline))
qonoff = [timeline, zeros(len(timeline))]
temps = Solve(timeline, qonoff)
```

It's not a solution yet, just a comment.